# JPA, why named parameter in native query is not replaced?

Tags: spring, parameters, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I tried both, indexed and named parameters, but it doesn't work:

```
public interface CharacterRepository extends JpaRepository<Character, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT * FROM Character WHERE pinyin like '%:keyword%'")
    List<Character> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
}
```

The outcoming sql is:

Hibernate:

```
   SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        Character 
    WHERE
        pinyin like '%:keyword%'
```

Why is the keyword-placeholder not replaced by the parameter I actually pass?

Comment: It is "not replaced" because it isnt a named parameter like that. It is (part of) a string literal (surrounded by quotes). You need to have it outside the quotes to be a parameter

Comment: @tobi Did our answers help you? Please don't forget to mark them...

Answer (score 3):

Your query should be like this -

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT * FROM Character c WHERE c.pinyin like %:keyword%")
 List<Character> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
public interface CharacterRepository extends JpaRepository<Character, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT * FROM Character WHERE pinyin like ':keyword'")
    List<Character> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
}
```

and call the method like this:

```
repository.findByKeyword("%myKeyword%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**JPQL/HQL**

```
select c from Character c where c.pinyin like %:keyword%
select c from Character c where c.pinyin like concat('%', :keyword, '%')
```

**Native (PostrgeSQL/MySQL)**

```
select * from character c where c.pinyin like concat('%', :keyword, '%')
```

**Native (PostrgeSQL)**

```
select * from character c where c.pinyin like '%' || :keyword || '%'
```

**Alternative variant with Spring Data JPA query method**

```
List<Character> findByPinyinContaining(String pinyin);
```

Additional info:

- [UserRepository examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/bf43e14fca009ff120513ec9bd48d47509c7ef3e/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java#L393)
- [Supported query keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_query_keywords)
- [JPQL standardized functions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-standardized-functions)